# SEO process for new wordpress site after upgrading from old HTML site

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, html

i have upgraded a old htlml site(created 15years back) to new wordpress site, when I search the site name in google it list out the home page and other inner page link such as about us, contact us etc

The inner page URLs are seems to be redirected to old website link such as `https://example.com/about.html` but my new link to be as `https://example.com/about-us/`

Is this all because of any old SEO process or Google web listings ie google business profile .

Do i have to do SEO process, if yes how long it will take to get changed or anything else to fix this

My original question is be
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256617/seo-process-for-new-wordpress-site-after-upgrading-from-old-html-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you modify your .htaccess file with redirects (preferably 301) to tell Google that your pages have moved?  If not, that would be a good place to give search engines the hint that you have reorganized you site.

From a search engine perspective, without the redirects from your side, you've simply deleted old pages and created new ones.  New pages often take 2-3 weeks for the pages to be indexed by Google, but may take longer to replace old pages without your creating the redirects.